# How can I make css curved line and button below

Tags: html, css

How can I make css like this as picture below:

[image]

```
<div class="logo">
  <img src="assets/logo/1.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="btn">
  <button>First</button>
  <button>First</button>
  <button>First</button>
  <button>First</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not place someone else to do it for you. Try to do it yourself and share your code.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to pull off - the curved line with the button in the middle? have you tried anything? I don't see any of your css.

Comment: use svg for the round effect

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with generated contents.

I have created an example for you

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
}

.logo {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
.logo:after {
  content: "";
  width: 300%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: gray;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -96%;
  left: -100%;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.btn {
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="logo">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any"/>
</div>
  <div class="btn">
  <button>First</button>
  <button>First</button>
  <button>First</button>
  <button>First</button>
</div>
</div>
```

and a pen: https://codepen.io/faw/pen/XRqdOq